# How to make the third textbox is depends on first and second textbox in c#.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm having this problems or this situation issues. I have five textboxes, where first two `textbox` users need to key in any values then next two text box will display the result by using the inserted values with some condition. Lastly, the another one `textbox` will display the new result based on the result that showed.

This is what i had tried :

```
private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    float value;


    if (float.TryParse(textBox3.Text, out value))
    {
        if (value < 1)
        {
            textBox4.Text = "1C";
        }

        else if (value >= 1 && value <2)
        {
            textBox4.Text = "5T";
        }


        else if (value >= 2)
        {
            textBox4.Text = "NG";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        textBox4.Text = "";
    }
}

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    float value;

    if (float.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out value))
    {
        if (value < 2)
        {
            textBox2.Text = "2T"; 
        }

        else if (value < 5 || value==2)
        {
            textBox2.Text = "5T";
        }


        else if (value > 5 )
        {
            textBox2.Text = "NG";
        }
        else 
        {
            textBox2.Text = "NG";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        textBox2.Text = ""; 
    }
}
```

if users enter values in "`textBox3`" it will show result at "`textBox4`',
if users enter values in "`textBox1`" it will show result at "`textBox2`"

I want to use the values from "`textBox4` and `textBox2`" to do some conditon checking then display the new result at "`textBox84`".

I tried to create the code and put it at load functions but nothing appears :

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please choose the correct FORM .",
        "Important Message !");

    var a = textBox4.Text.ToString();
    var b = textBox2.Text.ToString();

    if (a == "NG" && b == "NG")
    {
        textBox84.Text = "s";
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you set  AutoPostBack="True" for Textbox1 and Textbox3?

Comment: Not yet . Wait i'll try first

Comment: @KiranHegde are the way to set it , from the properties ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, unlike your `textBox3_TextChanged` your conditions in the `textBox1_TextChanged` can be simplified like this,

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    float value;

    if (float.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out value))
    {
        if (value < 2)
        {
            textBox2.Text = "2T"; 
        }

        else if (value < 5) //value==2 can be removed since it is covered in value < 5
        {
            textBox2.Text = "5T";
        }

        else //simply put else here, it is equivalent to what you did
        {
            textBox2.Text = "NG";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        textBox2.Text = ""; 
    }
}
```

Secondly, since your checking condition for `textBox84` is only done during the form load,

```
//This is in the Form1_Load
if (a == "NG" && b == "NG")
    {
        textBox84.Text = "s";
    }
```

it is unlikely to be executed as the text in `textBox2` and `textBox4` changed. All your initialization is actually done in the `Form1()` constructor, after `InitializeComponent`, not in the `Form1_Load`

To be safe, you should make event handlers for both `textBox2` and `textBox4` like what you did to `textBox1` and `textBox3`

```
private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox84.Text = textBox2.Text == "NG" && textBox4.Text == "NG" ? "s" : "";
}

private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox84.Text = textBox2.Text == "NG" && textBox4.Text == "NG" ? "s" : "";
}
```

This way, your `textBox84` really respond towards `textBox2` and `textBox4` `TextChanged` events, and not your `Form1_Load` event.

Side note:

The expression

```
if (textBox2.Text == "NG" && textBox4.Text == "NG")
    textBox84.Text = "s";
else 
    textBox84.Text = "";
```

Can be further simplified to

```
textBox84.Text = textBox2.Text == "NG" && textBox4.Text == "NG" ? "s" : "";
```

If you use Ternary Operator

Comment: Thank you very much @Ian. It solved the problems. !!! supeerb !!
Thank you also for your explanation and tips, i understand now

Comment: Great to know that. ;) the bottom line here is that you really code something which represents the real situation and not differently. For instance, since in this case you want to change `textBox84` depending on `textBox2` and `textBox4`, then you should code the way it is. ;)